# Dummy variables in Caret for Random Forest and Gradient Boosting

Tags: r, categorical-encoding, caret

Do caret 'creates' automatically the dummies for Random Forest and Gradient Boosting models, or do I have to do it previously with dummyVars()?

When I predict with the model, does caret handle the dummies in the predict data, too?

Thanks! :)